# How to use ServiceStack with custom login/token?

Tags: servicestack

I try to create a custom login with ServiceStack based on login/password and time.

To authenticate, I send a login, a token (calculate password based on unix time and a secret formula), and the same unix time.

The server calculate the token based on login and time and check if the token is the same as calculate.

Then I send all my request with the same login, same token, and a different time.

After a laps of time, the server's answer is "authentication timeout" and I must resign with the same method (same login, new token based on time) and time.

My question is : how can I tell ServiceStack to authenticate ?

For now I have this :

```
public class MyServiceAuthResponse
{
    public int success { get; set; }
}

public class RequireAuth
{
    public string mylogin{ get; set; }
    public double time { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
    public int? debug { get; set; }
}

[Route("/auth", "PUT")]
    public class MyServiceAuth : RequireAuth, IReturn<MyServiceAuthResponse>
    {
        public MyServiceAuth() { }

        public MyServiceAuth(string myLogin)
        {
            mylogin= myLogin;
            time = Math.Floor((DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalMilliseconds);
            token = CalculateToken(time);
        }
    }
```

And when I want to send authentication I use :

```
[Route("/document/create", "POST")]
public class CreateDocuments : RequireAuth, IReturn<DocumentsResponse>
{
    public Document data { get; set; }
    public Fichier file { get; set; }
}
```

and send the login/token and a new time.

My question is : how to tell ServiceStack to authenticate ? Is there a native way ? Or must I use my custom login ?
The problem is I must check each request return to know if I must resign or not.

Tell me if it's not clear enough, will try to explain clearly

Thanks a lot,

Comment: I precise it's "client side" so I can't change the authentication method.

Comment: Sound like you want to be using HMAC to securely sign your requests and only make them valid for a given period of time. Sending a password using `a secret formula` sounds risky - rolling your own secret sauce security is often flawed. Implementing HMAC, a widely adopted security pattern, allows you to authenticate requests without the requests sending a fixed token. It also allows detection of request tampering, and you can prevent request replays and restrict the validity of your request by time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the ServiceStack [Authentication and authorization](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization)

You are not suppose to put the authentication logic in the requestDto. You should create you own custom `AuthProvider` and override the `TryAuthenticate` method.

```
public class CustomBasicAuthProvider : BasicAuthProvider
{
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
    {
         time = Math.Floor((DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalMilliseconds);
         token = CalculateToken(time);

        // Your logic should go here
        var validToken = GetValidToken(userName)

        if (token == validToken )
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And register it int the `AppHost`

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new CustomBasicAuthProvider()
    }) { HtmlRedirect = null });
```

Comment: Excuse me Rachid, but the AppHost is server-side no ? I don't control server-side, only client-side. But maybe I'm wrong. Thanks a lot for your answer btw.

Comment: BaesFr, Not sure what you mean by server-side in this case. but if you can edit your requestDto I'm sure you can edit the AppHost as well. Just double check. If you find my suggestion too much for what u r trying to accomplish, use a [Request Filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) instead